# react datepicker custom dates for selection

Tags: reactjs, datepicker

Currently Im developing an datepicker from hackerone react datepicker, where user can select date from day up to decade, but I didnt find any props in DatePicker component at their website to give user opportunity to select decade, maximum is a year selection. I decided to put prop yearItemNumber={100} so it will give a range of 100 years, but how can I combine 10 years into one option as it show in first screen?

How it may look:

[image: datepicker i need to get]

What I have:

[image]

Also additional question, how can I display a century in datepicker header? Or its just a hardcoded text

Comment: What datepicker are you using? If you want some additional functionality, you're probably better of just building your own datepicker. Shouldn't be that hard.

Comment: React DatePicker